# Writing fool-proof applications vs writing for performance

Tags: performance

I'm biased towards writing fool-proof applications. For example with PHP site, I validate all the inputs from client-side using JS. On the server-side I validate again. On both sides I do validation for emptiness, and other patterns (email, phone, url, number, etc). And then I strip malicious tags or characters, trim them (server-side). Later I convert the input into desired formats/data types (string, int, float, etc). If the library meant for server-side only, I even give developers chances for graceful degradation and accommodate the tolerate the worst inputs and normalize to the acceptable ones (I have predefined set of the acceptable ones).

Now I'm reading a library that I wrote one and a half years ago. I'm wondering if developers are so evil or lack IQ for me do so much of graceful degradation, finding every possible chance to make the dudes right, even they gave crappy input which seriously harms performance. Or shall I do minimal checking and expect developers to be able and are willfully to give proper input? I have no hope for end-users but should I trust developers more and give them application/library with better performance?

Comment: I don't really have an opinion, except this one: Whichever you choose, document the hell out of it.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Could you please give more rationale or elaborate more? Thanks.

Comment: Foolproof + performance?

Comment: I'm slightly confused by your last paragraph, but to answer your subject: Do both.

Comment: Hi spender, when I do lots of checking and normalizing, time is wasted on correcting unnecessary errors instead of throwing exceptions to developers' faces.

Comment: @silky: Could you please let me know how could I make it clearer? Thanks.

Comment: Viet: Well, it sounds like you are writing libraries for 3rd party devs, but it also sounds like it's a public end-user system as well, and I'm slightly confused. Regardless, in my mind, there is no trade-off; making your API's handle input correct ( no context escaping or security issues ) is part of correctness; and there is *no other way* to even consider doing it.

Comment: +1 @Silky: I write both but at different times. The 2nd part was about writing a library.

Comment: Come up with a list of requirements based on your customer/user, treating these requirements as a high level spec, and coding to spec.  This includes usage scenarios, perf requirements, reliability requirements, usability requirements, etc.  It's hard to target a goal or known when you have reached it when you don't have one :)

This is different for every piece of software you write, unless you can reuse a previous model you have made (e.g. your audience/market is identical).

Once you have this doc, strive for correctness and maintainability until it breaks your perf requirements.

Comment: Thanks Merlyn! I wish could vote more for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Common policy is to validate on the server anything sent from the client because you can't be totally sure it really was your client that sent it.  You don't want to "trust developers more" and in the process find that you've "trusted hackers of your site more".

Fixing invalid input automatically can be as much a curse as a blessing -- you've essentially committed to accepting the *invalid* input as a *valid* part of your protocol (ie, in a future version if you make a change that will break the invalid input that you were correcting, it is no longer backwards compatible with the client code that has been written).  In extremis, you might paint yourself into a corner that way. Also, invalid calls tend to propagate to new code -- people often copy-and-paste example code and then modify it to meet their needs.  If they've copied bad code that you've been correcting at the server, you might find you start getting proportionally more and more bad data coming in, as well as confusing new programmers who think "that just doesn't look like it should be right, but it's the example everyone is using -- maybe I don't understand this after all".

Comment: +1 for the "Fixing invalid input automatically can be as much a curse as a blessing".

Answer (score 3):

Never expect diligence from developers. Always validate, if you can, any input that comes into your code, especially if it comes across a network.

Answer (score 2):

End users (whether they're programmers using your tool, or non-programmers using your application) don't have to be stupid or evil to type the wrong thing in.  As programmers we all too often make wrong assumptions about what's obvious for them.

That's the first thing, which justifies comprehensive validation all on its own.  But validation isn't the same as guessing what they meant from what they typed, and inferring correct input from incorrect - unless the inference rules are also well known to the users (like Word's auto-correct, for instance).

But what is this performance you seek?  There's no bit of client-side (or server-side, for that matter) validation that takes longer to run than the second or so that is an acceptable response time.

Validate, and ensure it doesn't break as the first priority.  Then worry about making it clever enough to know (reliably) what they meant.  After that, worry about how fast it is.  In the real world, syntax validation doesn't make a measurable difference to anything where user input takes most of the total time.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft made the mistake of trusting programmers to do the right thing back in the days of Windows 3.1 and to a lesser extent Windows 95.  You need only [read](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/10/21/483438.aspx) a [few](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2006/02/16/533250.aspx) [posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/06/18/9771135.aspx) from Raymond Chen to see where that road ultimately leads.

(P.S. This is not a dig against Microsoft - it's a statement on fact about how programmers abused the more liberal Win16, either deliberately or through ignorance)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right in being biased toward fool-proof applications. I would not assume that that degrades performance enough to be of much concern. Rather I would address performance concerns separately, starting by profiling or my favorite method, [stackshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406760/whats-your-most-controversial-programming-opinion/1562802#1562802). There must be a way to get those in PHP.